# Auto populating field from custom button

Tags: custom-button

I have a custom field called Contact__c in my Opportunity object.  It is a lookup to the Contact object. I created a custom button to send email so I could edit the URL to fill in the TO: field with Contact__c.  The custom button has the following in it:

```
/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p2_lkid={!Opportunity.Contact__c}&rtype=003&%2F0064000000cBDQe
```

This is not working because it's putting the the name in the url instead of the Contact Id.  Example:

```
https://na2.salesforce.com/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p2_lkid=Randy+Riegel&rtype=003&%2F0064000000cBDQe
```

If I edit the URL manually in my browser and change "Randy+Riegel" to the ID of that contact the field populates fine when refreshed.  How can I get the ID in the URL instead of the Name?

Comment: Have you tried `{!Opportunity.Contact__r.Id}`?

Comment: If I put that in the URL it will not let me save the button.  It says `{!Opportunity.Contact__r.Id}` does not exist.

Comment: Try creating a custom Text formula field in Opportunity called `ContactId__c` that is defined as `Contact__r.id`. Then reference {!ContactId__c} in the URL construction

Comment: But what if there is more than one contact?  Somehow I need to reference the custom field that has the "Primary Contact" in it.

Comment: if there is more than one contact, you are presumably talking about the members of the `OpportunityContactRole` sobject?  and you want to send an email to the primary OCR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If It was standard field you could have directly used the merge fields and put **{!Contact.Id}**

```
/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p2_lkid={!Contact.Id}&rtype=003&%2F0064000000cBDQe
```

But in your case, below approach will work.

So essentially what I did was created a custom field on Opportunity called as **'Primary_Sales_Contact__c'** and I tried to open the below URL that worked like a charm.

```
/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p2_lkid={! Opportunity.Primary_Sales_ContactId__c}
```

Comment: Hah, funny. I answered that and deleted it cause the OP said they were using a custom field Contact__c.

Comment: In your 'Primary_Sales_Contact_c' did you reference a custom field?   If you are referencing the contact object what would happen if there are more than one?   Don't I somehow have to reference "Contact__c"?

Comment: yes, this is a custom field. As this field is on Opportunity Object, it will always have a single Contact. How can you have more than one ? Do you have any such scenario? where is your 'Send Email'button positioned?

Comment: My send email button is at the top of the screen in the row of buttons that have Edit/Delete/Clone etc.    Does this make a difference?   Just now getting a change to work on this today.  Had to put out some other fires earlier

Comment: I created a text formula field that pointed to my other custom field.  Everything is working great now.